# XPath logical expression

Tags: xml, xpath, parentheses

I have a simple expression:

```
*[local-name() = 'test' and namespace-uri() = 'test1' or namespace-uri() = 'test2']"
```

This is something like:

```
 (x and y) or z
```

How to create the following expression:

```
x and (y or z)
```

I am using XPath 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
*[local-name() = 'test' and (namespace-uri() = 'test1' or namespace-uri() = 'test2')]"
```

or

```
*[local-name() = 'test' and namespace-uri() = ('test1','test2')]"
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, your first solution works for me. Thanks a lot!